# joomla 3, как редактировать / задавать дату создания материала в своей форме / используется renderField('created')

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

В кастомной форме редактирования материала, необходимо менять дату создания материала. Поле выводится с помощью:

```
echo $this->form->renderField('created');
```

Но не применяется указанная дата. При создании вставляется автоматом текущая дата, а при редактировании, в поле отображается реальная дата, изменив ее и сохранив материал она же и остается. Подскажите пожалуйста, где и что не учтено, на что обратить внимание? Все остальные поля работают без нареканий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в файле `/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml` меняем

```
<field 
    id = "created" 
    name = "created" 
    ... 
/>
```

на

```
<field
    id = "created" 
    name = "created" 
    type = "calendar" 
    label = "JGLOBAL_FIELD_CREATED_LABEL" 
    description = "JGLOBAL_FIELD_CREATED_DESC" 
    class = "inputbox" 
    format = ""
    filter = "user_utc"
/>
```